# Showing Bootstrap modal dialogs in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal dialog, which when Yes is selected returns a resolved promise.  Upon the promise being resolved, the modal should be displayed again. The line to display the modal is hit, but the modal does not display. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  showModalDialog('Confirm1', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
    .done(function() {
      alert('You selected Yes once!');
      showModalDialog('Confirm2', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
        .done(function() {
          alert('You selected Yes twice!');
        });
    });
});

function showModalDialog(title, message, button1Caption, button2Caption) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('#modalTitle').html(title);
  $('#modalMessage').html(message);
  $('#modalButton1').html(button1Caption);
  $('#modalButton2').html(button2Caption);
  $('#modalButton1').one('click', function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  $('#modalButton2').one('click', function() {
    deferred.reject();
  });
  $('#modalDialog').one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    //remove the handler for the button in case it was never invoked, otherwise it will
    //still be there the next time the dialog is shown
    $('#modalButton1').off('click');
    deferred.reject();
  })
  $('#modalDialog').modal();
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modalMessage"></div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modalButton1" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        <button type="button" id="modalButton2" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blame the animations! :)

The animation of the hiding modal takes some finite time to complete. If you try to "show" the modal again during this time, it will not work. A simple workaround is to delay the "show" action slightly.

For example, delaying it by one second will work just fine:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    showModalDialog('Confirm2', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
      .done(function() {
        alert('You selected Yes twice!');
      });
}, 1000);
```

```js
$(function() {
  showModalDialog('Confirm1', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
    .done(function() {
      alert('You selected Yes once!');
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        showModalDialog('Confirm2', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
          .done(function() {
            alert('You selected Yes twice!');
          });
      }, 1000);
    });
});

function showModalDialog(title, message, button1Caption, button2Caption) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('#modalTitle').html(title);
  $('#modalMessage').html(message);
  $('#modalButton1').html(button1Caption);
  $('#modalButton2').html(button2Caption);
  $('#modalButton1').one('click', function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  $('#modalButton2').one('click', function() {
    deferred.reject();
  });
  $('#modalDialog').one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    //remove the handler for the button in case it was never invoked, otherwise it will
    //still be there the next time the dialog is shown
    $('#modalButton1').off('click');
    deferred.reject();
  })
  $('#modalDialog').modal();
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modalMessage"></div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modalButton1" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        <button type="button" id="modalButton2" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I haven't checked the source code or experimented with these modals enough to know the minimum amount of delay required to make this work. But I don't mind a delay of one second anyway as it is barely noticeable.

### Update

As [you suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860165/showing-bootstrap-modal-dialogs-in-sequence/46860287?noredirect=1#comment80668266_46860287), waiting for Bootstrap's `hidden.bs.modal` event is a better in this case. As described in the [v3 Docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events):

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

So moving the `promise.resolved` to the event handler for `hidden.bs.modal` would also do the trick.

To do that, I've added a variable `modalResult` which keeps track of user's choice, and triggers `deferred.resolve` or `deferred.reject` accordingly.

```js
$(function() {
  showModalDialog('Confirm1', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
    .done(function() {
      alert('You selected Yes once!');
      
      showModalDialog('Confirm2', "Select Yes or No", 'Yes', 'No')
        .done(function() {
          alert('You selected Yes twice!');
        });
    });
});

function showModalDialog(title, message, button1Caption, button2Caption) {
  var modalResult = false;

  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('#modalTitle').html(title);
  $('#modalMessage').html(message);
  $('#modalButton1').html(button1Caption);
  $('#modalButton2').html(button2Caption);
  $('#modalButton1').one('click', function() {
    // Wait for the modal to get hidden.
    // deferred.resolve();
    modalResult = true;
  });
  $('#modalButton2').one('click', function() {
    // Wait for the modal to get hidden.
    // deferred.reject();
    modalResult = false;
  });
  $('#modalDialog').one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    //remove the handler for the button in case it was never invoked, otherwise it will
    //still be there the next time the dialog is shown
    $('#modalButton1').off('click');
    
    if(modalResult) {
      deferred.resolve();
    } else {
      deferred.reject();
    }
  })
  $('#modalDialog').modal();
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modalMessage"></div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modalButton1" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
        <button type="button" id="modalButton2" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals), they say for `hidden.bs.modal`: **This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).**

Comment: I guess moving `deferred.resolve();` to `hidden.bs.modal` event would solve the problem as well, without guessing how many seconds to add

Comment: @ljubadr Yup that would be a better approach.

Comment: Updated the post. Btw you seem to be doing something quite similar to [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/). You should check it out. I think they use callbacks instead of promises though.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks guys.  I had not seen Bootbox before, I'll check it out.